# HAproxy gpt0 does not trigger backend selection

Tags: linux, haproxy

I have a frontend definition that looks like this:

```
frontend fe_imap from defaults_1
  mode tcp
  bind 127.0.0.1:143
  bind [::1]:143
  bind x.x.x.x:143
  stick-table type ip size 100k expire 24h store gpt0
  option tcplog
  use_backend block_imap if { sc_get_gpt0(0) eq 1 }
  use_backend %[src,map_ip(/etc/haproxy/maps/blacklist-imap.map)]
  default_backend be_imap
```

My idea is to block some IPs for only an amount of time and others permanently. The latter already woks perfectly. I do updates on the map and the table with the runtime API.

For some reason the gpt0 idea does not work. I entered this at the command prompt:

```shell
echo "set table fe_imap src 127.0.0.1 data.gpt0 1" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
```

which added the IP (just a localhost example. In real life that will be remote IPs)

```shell
echo "show table fe_imap" | socat stdio /var/run/haproxy.sock
# table: fe_imap, type: ip, size:102400, used:1
0x7fe788035988: key=127.0.0.1 use=0 exp=85159306 shard=0 gpt0=1
```

And if I try “telnet 127.0.0.1 143” I still land on the default backend and not the block_imap backend.

Can somebody help me with this?